# Upload Multiple Files Through Imgur

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, imgur

I'm using this code to upload multiple files to imgur at once but its not working. It doesn't even trigger at all;

```
<form action="imgur.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Send these files:<br />
  <input name="file[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" onchange="upload(this.files[0])" />
</form>

<?php 
foreach ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $index => $tmpName) {
    if( !empty( $tmpName ) && is_uploaded_file( $tmpName ) )
    {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.ondragover = function(e) {e.preventDefault()}
    window.ondrop = function(e) {e.preventDefault(); upload(e.dataTransfer.files[0]); }
    function upload(file) {


        if (!file || !file.type.match(/image.*/)) return;


        document.body.className = "uploading";


        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("image", file);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json");
        xhr.onload = function() {
            var code = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).data.link + '\n';
            var editor = eval('opener.' + 'clickableEditor');
            editor.performInsert(code);
            javascript:window.close()
        }

        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Client-ID [MY-CLIENT-ID]');

        xhr.send(fd);
    }
</script>

<?php
}
}
?>
```

The file name this code is pasted is named as `imgur.php`

Please help!

Comment: you're going about this the wrong way, if you've got the tools to do this serverside, then do so. It'll be quicker and easier.

Comment: What do you mean by tools? javascript or jquery both libraries are present in my server.